# Cleanest way to identify an entity with Doctrine inheritance mapping in zf2

Tags: doctrine-orm, routes, zend-framework2, mapping, single-table-inheritance

I am using Doctrine inheritance mapping in a project which produces a set of unique entities that each extend a base entity.  Because the route is not aware of which entities go with which base rows, I have to query the database twice in order to grab the row I want from the right fieldset:

```
// in a controller action:

    // locate the event entity record and determine the event type
    $entity = 'AdminEvents\Entity\Event';
    $event = $this->getEntityManager()->find($entity, $eventID);
    $eventType = $this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata(get_class($event))->discriminatorValue;

    // locate the record we're really looking for in the unique extended entity
    $entity = 'AdminEvents\Entity\\' . $eventType;
    $event = $this->getEntityManager()->find($entity, $eventID);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define an `\AdminEvents\Entity\AbsractEvent` class, if you haven't already. Then each of your STI entities should extend this, and you can do `instanceof` (or other logic) to find out what concrete type you got:

```
    // locate the record using the AbstractEntity
    $entity = 'AdminEvents\Entity\AbstractEntity';
    $event = $this->getEntityManager()->find($entity, $eventID);
```

A word of caution: the SPL function, `get_class` will often return the Doctrine Proxy class, so don't rely on that directly to test the return type. You can use the Doctrine class 'ClassUtils'

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils::getRealClass(get_class($event));
```